# How to fetch the list of users from ParseUser table and show the it in list view in andorid

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to get the list of first names of all the users from ParseUser table but its crashing with the error: doing much work on main thread. It works when I try fetch from other ParseObjects but it doesn't work with ParseUser table. The following is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Declare Variables
      ListView listview;
      List<ParseUser> ob;
      ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, APP, SECRET);
       new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }

        // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("loading all donors");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        try {
            ob = query.find();

        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.listview_item);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject User : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) User.get("firstName"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items

         }
      }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#de99ac"
     tools:context="com.nyu.blife_app.MainActivity">
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

listview_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5sp"
   android:textSize="25sp" >
 </TextView>
```

I have added additional fields in ParseUser table (firstName, lastName) and some more.. I just need to get all the firstNames from ParseUser Table. it would be really helpful if someone guide me on this.

Comment: Why do you use an `AsyncTask`? Parse objects and queries have async methods for many operations.

Comment: For example `query.findInBackground(FindCallback)`.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/

Comment: I think it's a bit old and not too great. You're better off using the build in async methods in Parse and the adapters written specifically for `ListView`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a bit flawed, but it could be because the tutorial you linked is a bit old. I think there's a much better approach.

First of all, your `ProgressDialog` should probably be replaced with a `ProgressBar` (see the Android tutorial on [Progress & Activity](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html)).

Secondly, I think you should really be using a `ParseQueryAdapter` and let Parse handle everything for you. There's an [official tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter) on this, but I will explain it briefly:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(this, APP, SECRET);

        listView = (ListView)findVIewById(R.id.listview);

        UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

                return query;
            }
        });

        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                // show progress bar
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseUser> list, Exception e) {
                // close progress bar
            }
        });

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

where `UsersAdapter` is defined as

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, QueryFactory<ParseUser> queryFactory) {
        super(context, queryFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseUser user, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // build your views
    }
}
```

So you create your `ListView` as usual, but you add a special adapter to it that (1) queries Parse for the stuff you want using the query you provide and (2) adds these results to the `ListView` - you will need to provide an implementation to `getItemView`.

You may want to do something with your `ProgressBar` in the `OnQueryLoadListener`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call 
    new Runnable(){
    void run(){
     new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }
    }.run();

Instead of 
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

Comment: I have tried replacing with your solution, now it doesn't crash but I  guess its not even executing because even progress bar is not showing up

Comment: Yes you are right Yash. You need to run the runnable. See my edit.