# How to make a ListView from a Specific List<ParseUser>?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-listview

I'm trying to make a listview from a list containing ParseUser.
My search class returns: List
Parse SDK 1.12 does not support ParseQueryAdapter any more and the profile adapter function does not take ParseUser.

I tried to query the ParseObjects from the `_User` Class of parse but it wouldn't return the objects.

So i'm working in circels, if I try to get the User information in ParseObject I don't get it. If I work with ParseUser I can't make the ListView. Does someone know a way to get around it?

I already checked this questions.

[ParseUser Username Adapter in Android ListView doesn't show Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475596/parseuser-username-adapter-in-android-listview-doesnt-show-data)

and

[How to fetch the list of users from ParseUser table and show the it in list view in andorid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870415/how-to-fetch-the-list-of-users-from-parseuser-table-and-show-the-it-in-list-view)

But it doesn't work with a specified List of Users.

This is my code.

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Search search;
    EditText mCityField;
    List<ParseUser> mAccountList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        mCityField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mCityField);
    }

    public void searchCity(View v){
        if(mCityField.getText().toString().length()!=0){
            mAccountList = search.searchUsers(mCityField.getText().toString());
            Log.i("main", "succesfully searched yo mamma");
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a city!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This is my Search Class:

```
public class Search {
    List<ParseUser> locals = null;

    public List<ParseUser> searchUsers(String city){
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("City", city);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("main", "inside if loop" + userList);

                    for (ParseUser user : userList) {
                        Log.i("main", "inside for loop");
                        String username = user.getString("username");
                        Log.i("main", "username " + username);
                    }
                    locals = userList;
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        return locals;
    }
}
```

Adapter CLass:

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {
    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, QueryFactory<ParseObject> queryFactory) {
        super(context, queryFactory);
    }
    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseUser user, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // build your views
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a whole class for the `searchUsers` method? Can't you just include that method in the Activity?

Comment: It doesn't need to be but I want to seperate the querys from my main activity.

Comment: Sure, sure... Where is the `ListView` in your code? I don't it or where you initialize an adapter. Also, `query.findInBackground` runs *asynchronously*, so `return locals` will most likely be `null` when it is evaluated.

Comment: You really should be following this example. https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

Comment: But there is no possibility to extend ParseQueryAdapter as a subclass any more. Is there another way or another subclass which gives the same result?

Comment: What do you mean? That tutorial mentions `CustomAdapter` which looks like a subclass of `ParseQueryAdapter`

Comment: I found what you are referring to - please see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/21

Comment: cricket you are right! I only needed to add compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'  to my gradle and then it recognized the QueryAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using an asynchronous method `query.findInBackground`
where the `done` method will only be called once the asynchronous call returns. Until this occurs your `locals` List will remain null and as you are returning it instantly after within a synchronous method you are just returning an empty list from your `searchUsers` method.

Place a call to the method within the `done` block that either creates a new `ProfileAdapter` and set it as the adapter for your ListView or even better, initialize the ListView with the adapter when the view is created and add a method to update the data set on the adapter, after which call `notifyDatasetChanged` on your adapter and voila it will add the results to your ListView.

Something like:

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

private List<ParseUser> mUserList;

public ProfileAdapter(Context context, QueryFactory<ParseObject> queryFactory) {
super(context, queryFactory);
}

@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseUser user, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
// build your views
}

public void setData(List<ParseUser>  userList) {
    mUserList = userList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mUserList.size();
}
```

Call this `setData` method on your adapter from your `done` callback method. This will set the returned data in your adapter and notify it that there is new data to display. Also remember to set the adapter as the adapter for your ListView in your Activity.

Comment: Ideally, the `queryFactory` variable should be fetching the list, not requiring the list to be passed in after the fact.

Comment: But the thing is that the newest Parse SDK 1.12 doesn't support ParseQueryAdapter any more. So I'm trying to find an alternative